# Здравствуйте! есть простая задача: при нажатии на кнопку свойство width картинки увеличивается в 2 раза, но оно не видит значения передаваемые в width

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>dwd</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img
      id="img"
      style="width: 250px"
      src="https://biogr.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screenshot_11.jpg"
      alt="5y"
    />
    <p id="p"></p>

    <button
      id="button"
      type="submit"
      style="position: absolute; left: 800px; top: 200px; display: inline"
    >
      ТЫЧ!!!
    </button>

    <script defer>
      let valueofpxsizeimg = Number(
        document.querySelector("#img").style.width[0] +
          document.querySelector("#img").style.width[1] +
          document.querySelector("#img").style.width[2]
      );

      let button = document.querySelector("#button");
      document.write('"' + String(valueofpxsizeimg * 2) + "px" + '"');
      button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.querySelector("#img").style.width =
          '"' + String(valueofpxsizeimg * 2) + "px" + '"';
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: если руками писать document.querySelector("#img").style.width = "500px" все работает, а вот как передать туда значение *2

Answer (score 0):

Просто уберите кавычки:

```
document.querySelector("#img").style.width = String(valueofpxsizeimg * 2) + "px";
```

Comment: Спасибо!помогло!)